# Regex in Shell script

Tags: regex, shell

I want to get rid of texts like "uc010obu.2:" in each line. I tried to write the following, but the pattern is not recognizable.

```
%s/uc(\d\+)(\w\+).(\d\+)://
```

Could someone help with the right pattern? thanks

each line is something like this:

```
CPEB2 uc010obu.2:c.1070_1071insCGG:p.G357delinsGG
```

ps: I am trying to do in vim editor.

Comment: Can you also give us the text you are trying to perform the regexp on? it gives us something to reference and test on.

Comment: Is that being used as an argument to `sed`? `vim`? Something else? Why are you grouping those matches if you are throwing it all away?

Comment: Is the text you are removing always two letters followed by three numbers three letters a period a number and ends with a colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not group your regex.

```
:%s/uc\d\+\w\+\.\d\+://
```

if you want to group, use `\(` and `\)` instead. if you are using perl-compatible tool, it's `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex in `vim/sed`:

```
%s/uc\d\+\w\+\.\d\+://
```

Or else:

```
g/uc\d\+\w\+\.\d\+:/d
```

Comment: but uc010obu.2 can be ucxxxxxx.x

Comment: Sorry, bad copy/paste fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match text with only the varying numbers you can try this pattern:

```
uc(\d+)(\w+).(\d+):
```

To try, you can use the website http://rubular.com/